# How to understand the statement of Exercise 6.19 on Fulton's Algebraic Curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, zariski-topology

I think that I am not fully understanding what the exercise asks me to show. Here it is:

[image]

(Fulton, *Algebraic Curves*, 2008)

By definition, a variety $X$ is an open subset of $V$, where $V$ is an irreducible algebraic subset. Here $\mathcal{O}_p(X)=\mathcal{O}_p(V)$ for every $p\in X$, and $\varphi$ is just the function induced by $f$.

But, unless I have misunderstood, what the exercise asks me to show is false. If we fix $\lambda \in k$, then the pole set of $z=\frac{1}{f-\lambda}$ is the set of all $P\in V$ such that $f(P)=\lambda$. In order to prove this, let $Q$ be the pole set of $z$ and let's show that $Q=f^{-1}(\lambda)$. It is obvious that $Q\subseteq f^{-1}(\lambda)$. To prove the reverse inclusion, we must show that if $z=\frac{a}{b}$ where $a,b\in \Gamma(V)$, then $b(v)=0$ for every $v\in f^{-1}(\lambda)$. But this is easy, because $b=(f-\lambda)a$.

Ok, so $\varphi^{-1}(\lambda)=f^{-1}(\lambda)\cap X$ is missing all the elements in the pole set of $z$ which do not lie in $X$, am I right? Of course, maybe it is possible to show that all the elements in the pole set of $f$ lie in $X$, but that seems quite impossible. I mean; it would be almost the same as proving that the pole set of any element of $\Gamma(V)$ which can be written as $\frac{1}{a}$ is a subset of every open subset of $V$, which I do not expect to be true.

Maybe we have to change the definition of pole set when we are dealing with open subsets of irreducible algebraic sets?

Comment: It's not true that the rings of functions of $X$ and $V$ must be the same: consider $V=\Bbb A^1$ and $X=V\setminus \{0\}$. Then the ring of functions of the former is $k[x]$ while the latter is $k[x,x^{-1}]$ which aren't isomorphic, let alone equal. This also shows that you can't necessarily extend $\varphi$ to a function on $V$. Your stated confusion also seems to arise exactly when you decide that the pole set of $\varphi$ is somehow a subset of $V$ instead of $X$: why do you do this? Lastly, if you're interested in whether you need to change your definition, can you post your current one?

Comment: Thank you. You're right, I was confused. I did not meant to say $\Gamma(X)=\Gamma(V)$. I was actually thinking of $\mathcal{O}_p(X)=\mathcal{O}_p(V)$ and $k(X)=k(V)$ (page 69 on Fulton's book). I will fix it. Now: for the definition of a pole set, I was supposing that the pole set is a subset of $V$ precisely because of the equality $k(X)=k(V)$. Since Fulton does not define the pole set of an element in $\Gamma(X)$, I thought that it was the same definition as in the simple case.

Comment: I think all of your confusions should go away if you stop thinking about $V$. If you just run everything on $X$, then the pole set of $\frac{1}{f-\lambda}$ should be exactly the points where $f=\lambda$. (You still haven't given _any_ definition of a pole set, which is rather silly when your question is all about whether the "usual definition" is sufficient or needs to be changed - if you actually want an answer, I would highly recommend picking a definition.)